# AWS CodePipeline failing at deploy stage with CloudFormation error

Tags: node.js, aws-cloudformation, continuous-deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

AWS CodePipeline is failing at deploy stage. This is the error I receive:

```
Deployment completed, but with errors: Failed to deploy application.
Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:

[/Resources/AWSEBAutoScalingGroup/Metadata/AWS::CloudFormation::Init/prebuild_1_My_API/files//etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf] 
'null' values are not allowed in templates
```

I'm trying to deploy to an Elastic Beanstalk environment. Here is my buildspec.yml file:

```
version: 0.1
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - npm test
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

I'm using the `aws/codebuild/standard:1.0` docker image.

Any ideas?

Comment: what template are you using?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?

"AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09"